# How to delete word(s) from UserDictionary with specifying locale?

Tags: android, android-userdictionary

I have a couple of input types and each has its own words in the personal dictionary (UserDictionary). I want to delete a word(s) from one input type/ one locale.

I tried the following but the app crashes:

```
getContentResolver().delete(UserDictionary.Words.CONTENT_URI,
UserDictionary.Words.LOCALE + " = en_US", null);
```

The error says:

> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: en_US (code
>   1): , while compiling: DELETE FROM words WHERE locale = en_US

Comment: Please note that many keyboard apps keep their own dictionaries, rather than using the system one.  There is nothing you can do programmatically to remove it from there.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax was wrong. The correct syntax is as following:

```
getContentResolver().delete(UserDictionary.Words.CONTENT_URI,
UserDictionary.Words.LOCALE + "=?", new String[] {"en_US"});
```